# Как составить словарь из XAML файла

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, локализация

У меня есть такой xaml файл, в котором есть куча разных слов и их теги, как скопировать все эти слова без тегов?[image: мой словарь]

Comment: Notepad++ поддерживает регулярки.

Comment: XAML - это валидный XML. Так что можно воспользоваться любым xml-парсером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безрегулярный вариант на C#

```csharp
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"filename.xaml");
string[] result = lines.Select(x => string.Join(" ", x.Split('<', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                                      .Select(y => y.Substring(y.IndexOf('>') + 1))).Trim())
                       .Where(x => x?.Length > 0).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"text.txt", result);
```

Может сработать не совсем правильно, если тег `<...>` занимает несколько строк.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще так (добавить ссылки на PresentationFramework и System.Xaml):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object LoadXaml(string path)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            using (sr)
            {
                object el = XamlReader.Load(sr.BaseStream);
                return el;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResourceDictionary rd = LoadXaml("...") as ResourceDictionary;

            if (rd == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File is not a resource dictionary");
                return;
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var x in rd.Keys)
            {
                sb.AppendLine((string)rd[x]);
            }

            string res = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно решение на C# попробуйте воспользоваться этим кодом:

```
string input = "...";
var expression = @"(\<(/?[^>]+)>)";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, expression, "");
```